# Javascript Code rendered on webpage

Tags: jquery, django, bootbox

I am using the bootbox JavaScript library plugin to create a dialog box if a form validation error is raised. The code works fine - the dialog box appears as expected - but somehow the code itself is printed/ rendered on the webpage as well:

[image: Screenshot]

The code I am using is:

```
<form class='form-horizontal' method="POST" action=""> {% csrf_token %}
      <div class='form-group form-group-lg'>
       {% if form.email.errors %}
        {% for err in form.email.errors %}
          bootbox.alert("Verrate uns noch deine Mail :)")
        {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
         <input required class='form-control' type="email" name="email"   placeholder="Deine Email..."/>
</form>
```

I tried wrapping the `bootbox.alert` around a `<script>` or wrap the whole code snipper around a `{% block jquery %}` but neither helped.

EDIT 1:
I looked at the console and the output seems to be fine, according to my understanding: Screenshot

As far as I understood and by what I read about them, the two errors showing up do not matter.

I saw some other threads where people ran into similar difficulties and their problem was often related to a typo etc. Here is the full code for the form maybe you spot something I have not spotted so far:

```
<form class='form-horizontal' method="POST" action=""> {% csrf_token %}
<div class='form-group form-group-lg'>
        {% if form.email.errors %}
         {% for err in form.email.errors %}
          bootbox.alert("Verrate uns noch deine Mail :)");
         {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
<input required class='form-control' type="email" name="email" placeholder="Deine Email..."/>
</br>
      {% if form.wunschrad.errors %}
        {% for err in form.wunschrad.errors %}
      <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">Verrate uns noch dein Wunschrad :)</div>
      {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}

    <select required class="form-control" type="text" name="wunschrad">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Dein Wunschrad...</option>
      <option>Sportlich (z.B. Rennrad oder Fixie)</option>
      <option>Klassisch (z.B. Holland- oder Waffenrad)</option>
    </select>
    </br>
      <input type='submit' value='Anmelden' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg'/>
```

when I put any script tags around the bootbox it does not work any more, without script tags the dialog box pops up perfectly fine

EDIT 2: Below the output from my browser's view source:

```
<form class='form-horizontal' method="POST" action=""> <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='EF6C3vzUocRy0TxoMnCvp0G4VNomkoBG' />
      <div class='form-group form-group-lg'>

              bootbox.alert("Hello world!");

<input required class='form-control' type="email" name="email" placeholder="Deine Email..."/>

 </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem:

1.) I created a new html file including only the bootbox alert code wrapped in a `<script>` tag. This worked: dialog box popped up as expected and the code was not shown on the page itself

2.) I started copying all the remaining code step by step from the old to the new html file and checked if the bootbox alert is still working

3.) In the end the only difference between my not working old file and working new file was that in my new file this code snippet

```
<!-- JS dependencies -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>

<!-- bootbox code -->
<script src="{% static 'js/bootbox.min.js' %}"></script>
```

was loading in my base.html file and I used `{% extends "base.html" %}` to reference to it. Now that I have this snippet directly in my html, everything works.

Comment: You should update this as an edit to your quesiton, but you haven't applied the fix that Praveen Kumar has provided you.

Answer (score 3):

Just add `<script>` tags:

```
<form class='form-horizontal' method="POST" action=""> {% csrf_token %}
  <div class='form-group form-group-lg'>

    {% if form.email.errors %}
      <script>
        {% for err in form.email.errors %}
        bootbox.alert("Verrate uns noch deine Mail :)");
        {% endfor %}
       </script>
    {% endif %}
    <input required class='form-control' type="email" name="email"   placeholder="Deine Email..."/>
  </div>
</form>
```

Also mind that you have not closed `<div>`.

**Note:** This might be annoying for the users, as it would show a lot of alerts. So I would say, it is better to collect all the message and show it as a single message:

```
<form class='form-horizontal' method="POST" action=""> {% csrf_token %}
  <div class='form-group form-group-lg'>
    {% if form.email.errors %}
    <script>
      var message = "";
        {% for err in form.email.errors %}
          message += "Verrate uns noch deine Mail :) <br />";
        {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
      bootbox.alert(message);
    </script>
    {% endif %}
    <input required class='form-control' type="email" name="email"   placeholder="Deine Email..."/>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: @Sayse it would be better not to bother with the `for` loop at all, given the same message is being shown repeatedly.

Comment: I would also suggest collecting all the messages and showing it in a single bootbox.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - In this case yes, but that isn't what the question was about and the op may be planning on changing the contents. Praveen Kumar, I meant inside of the if statement so there isn't any chance of an empty script but either works :)

Comment: @Sayse See the updated answer and tell me what you feel. This would be better with the user experience.

Comment: @PraveenKumar - I'm not sure how aware you are of django but essentially each `err` would be a different error based on what validation failed so it would end up being `bootbox.alert("{{ err }}")`, but then I'm not familiar with bootbox so yes it may be more sensible as you've suggested!

Comment: @Sayse I am zero in django, so feel free to correct my answer with the right thing. `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar thanks for your response. I tried your code but now the dialog box isn't appearing, which I don't really understand...does anyone know if there are some problems using the <script> tag with Django apps?

Comment: @Daniel How is it rendering?

Comment: @Sayse Would you like to advice Daniel on this?

Comment: @Daniel - There aren't any problems with using the script tag with django. (For all, django renders a html template on the server side so by the time you get to the client you are left with raw html/javascript). The problem is somewhere else. Start by checking the console as per normal with js

Comment: Sorry for the second post, I am new to stackoverflow so still getting familiar with the rules. I tried the suggested solutions but unfortunately they don't work, when I wrap the JQuery Code around a <script> tag the code is not read (the dialog window is not popping up), whereas when I leave them out, it works but the code itself is shown as well on the webpage

Comment: @Daniel Ah that looks crazy. What exactly is outputted in the View Source for the solution I gave?

Comment: I thought I might have to put the jScript code into the head of the html document and only reference it in the body but I don't know if this is possible at all?

Comment: @Daniel Just a simple question. How is the above code rendered in your browser's View Source? We can take it from there. Also check your console for more errors, if any.

Comment: @Daniel Edit your post bro. :)